# Cannot list ansible collections

Tags: ansible

**How can I list the collections installed in ansible?**


According to the ansible documentation (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html#listing-collections), the collections installed in ansible can be listed with the following command:

`ansible-galaxy collection list`

Or, by also specifying the path (e.g., the default path given in the link above): 
`ansible-galaxy collection list -p "~/.ansible/collections"`

However, both result in the following error:
`ansible-galaxy collection list usage: ansible-galaxy collection [-h] COLLECTION_ACTION ... ansible-galaxy collection: error: argument COLLECTION_ACTION: invalid choice: 'list' (choose from 'init', 'build', 'publish', 'install')`

ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to a version of Ansible that supports listing collections. Ansible 2.9 is ancient and only has limited collection support; if you refer to its documentation (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/collections_using.html) you will see that it does not include this section, while 2.10's documentation (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/collections_using.html#listing-collections) does.

Comment: Didn't realize ansible package in Ubuntu/apt was so out of date.

Comment: Also on fedora 35 it is `ansible 2.9.27` and `ansible-galaxy 2.9.27`.

Answer (score 0):

To help those stuck with Ansible 2.9 and older, 
there is a very nice Python-script by [Brian Coca](https://github.com/bcoca) -
see https://github.com/bcoca/std/blob/devel/list_collections.py

(have found this script mentioned in [Ansible-Galaxy issue #2844](https://github.com/ansible/galaxy/issues/2844) and [Ansible issue #76497](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/76497))